# Perform Calculation After Certain Row in SQL Group By

Tags: sql, group-by

My table looks like this [(DB Fiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eZrhracGaYHd6WDn1z2Xoe/1)

| GROUP_ID | IX_IN_GROUP | USER_ID | MEASUREMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 101 | 80 |
| 1 | 3 | 100 | 106 |
| 1 | 4 | 101 | 140 |
| 1 | 5 | 100 | 182 |
| 1 | 6 | 101 | 207 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 101 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 100 | 37 |
| 2 | 4 | 101 | 59 |
| 2 | 5 | 100 | 63 |

For each group, I want to first find the measurement associated with the first row that the user with USER_ID 101 has within that group (call this X). I then want to find the last/max measurement value (regardless of USER_ID) in the group (call this Y). My expected output would thus be:

| GROUP_ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 207 |
| 2 | 6 | 63 |

Getting the Y values is trivial

```
GROUP_ID,
MAX(measurement) as Y
FROM table1
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
ORDER BY GROUP_ID
```

but, calculating X and then joining the 2 queries is escaping me at the moment.

Comment: Given that rows in a table have no intrinsic order, how are you defining which is the first row for USER_ID 101 within a group?

Comment: Do you have date/time column or some other type of sequence column to help determine the order?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, the increasing values in 'measurement' give the ordering, or I've added in the (IX_IN_GROUP) column now. @Isolated In reality, I do have a date/time column in my dataset, but this is just a simplified version of the query

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Are you allowed to use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function?

Comment: @Reveson I'm using Snowflake, so yes I can use the ROW_NUMBER() window function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the aggregate functions `MAX()` and `MIN()` combined with CASE clause :

```
SELECT 
GROUP_ID,
MIN(CASE WHEN USER_ID = 101 THEN measurement END ) AS X,
MAX(measurement) as Y
FROM table1
GROUP BY GROUP_ID;
```

Results :

```
GROUP_ID    X   Y
1           80  207
2           6   63
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GZwJaBVcPR4gYif1h1TMo/0)

Comment: Upvoting, best answer.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about `CASE`. Very clever!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. :)

Try this query:

```sql
WITH FirstMeasurement AS (
    SELECT GROUP_ID, MEASUREMENT,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GROUP_ID order by MEASUREMENT) as rn
    FROM table1
    WHERE USER_ID = 101
),
LastMeasurement AS (
    SELECT GROUP_ID,
           MAX(measurement) as Y
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY GROUP_ID
)
SELECT fm.GROUP_ID, fm.MEASUREMENT as X, lm.Y
FROM FirstMeasurement fm
JOIN LastMeasurement lm ON fm.GROUP_ID = lm.GROUP_ID
WHERE fm.rn = 1
ORDER BY fm.GROUP_ID;
```

Here is a link to DB Fiddle, showing desired result: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5UMNmTMxiVezK1YuQ9Dtpd/0

**#Edit**
There is also simpler solution if we can order the rows by the `MEASUREMENT` column:

```sql
WITH FirstMeasurement AS (
    SELECT GROUP_ID, min(MEASUREMENT) as X
    FROM table1
    WHERE USER_ID = 101
    GROUP BY GROUP_ID
),
LastMeasurement AS (
    SELECT GROUP_ID,
           MAX(measurement) as Y
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY GROUP_ID
)
SELECT fm.GROUP_ID, fm.X, lm.Y
FROM FirstMeasurement fm
JOIN LastMeasurement lm ON fm.GROUP_ID = lm.GROUP_ID
ORDER BY fm.GROUP_ID;
```

If you need to order the rows by other column, then of course use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function.

Comment: Great, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE to get the Y value...

```
with y_value as (SELECT 
 GROUP_ID,
 MAX(measurement) as Y
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY GROUP_ID
 )
select 
 t.group_id, 
 min(measurement) as X, 
 y.y as Y
 from table1 t
 join y_value y
   on t.group_id = y.group_id
 where user_id = 101
 group by 1,3;
```

| group_id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 207 |
| 2 | 6 | 63 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eZrhracGaYHd6WDn1z2Xoe/1)